# multiple screens has moved task bar and my laptop screen is no longer the main screen

Tags: display, multiple-monitors

I have a laptop (windows 10) and two monitors. In the display setting I have been able to drag the screen into the order I want.

So number 1 (my laptop) is on my left. The other monitors are the middle (number 2) & right (number 3).

My main taskbar with my battery life and other things had moved to screen number 2, no idea why. So I found that I could unlock it and move it to my laptop screen. However when I switch everything off I have to move the taskbar back again to my laptop screen. Also when I have to log on the screen that comes on first & asks for my password is screen number 2. How do I make my laptop screen the 'main' screen?

Comment: Do [these methods](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3871-change-main-display-windows-10-a.html) for setting the primary monitor work for you?

Comment: Provide a screenshot of your Display Settings within Settings.  We also need a screenshot of Taskbar within Settings.  Provide both of these screenshots by performing an [edit] to your quesiton.

Comment: @harrymc, thank you very much the first method worked for me. If you post you comment as answer I will mark it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method will set the display to be use as the main display for all users by default:

- Right-click the desktop and select "Display settings"
- Position to the "Display" section
- Click on the display number at the top that you want to make the main display
- Check "Make this my main display box under Multiple displays".

For more details see the article
[How to Set a Display as Main Display in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3871-change-main-display-windows-10-a.html).